# DBpedia REST API

Tags: dbpedia

http://dbpedia.org/page/IBM

Can anyone suggest how can I use DBpedia REST API to get the fields that are displayed in above link like, e.g., founded by, assets, etc.

Any kind of suggestion would be extremely helpful.

Comment: I don't know that DBpedia *has* a REST API.  Have you seen it suggested somewhere that it does?

Comment: The SPARQL Protocol might be considered to be DBpedia's REST API, accessed via [http://dbpedia.org/sparql/](http://dbpedia.org/sparql/) ... but it's not at all clear what the OP wants/needs to do.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this api: https://github.com/dbpedia/ontology-driven-api

This project is based on REST Api.

Comment: Do you have any idea if these APIs are hosted for public somewhere? I managed to find a hosted version of the lookup API but not for the SPARQL endpoint API.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly [this query](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=SELECT+DISTINCT+%3Fp%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A++%7B+%0D%0A++++OPTIONAL+%7B+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FIBM%3E++%3Fp++%3Fo++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%7D%0D%0A++++OPTIONAL+%7B++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%3Fs++%3Fp++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FIBM%3E+%7D%0D%0A++%7D%0D%0AORDER+BY+%3Fp&format=text%2Fx-html%2Btr&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on) ([results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT+DISTINCT+%3Fp%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A++%7B+%0D%0A++++OPTIONAL+%7B+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FIBM%3E++%3Fp++%3Fo++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%7D%0D%0A++++OPTIONAL+%7B++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%3Fs++%3Fp++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FIBM%3E+%7D%0D%0A++%7D%0D%0AORDER+BY+%3Fp&format=text%2Fx-html%2Btr&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)) is what you were looking for...

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?p
WHERE
  { 
    OPTIONAL { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/IBM>  ?p  ?o                                }
    OPTIONAL {                                ?s  ?p  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/IBM> }
  }
ORDER BY ?p
```